# Subdomain versus .mobi domain

Tags: domains, mobile

I'm planning to extend an existing website by a version which is optimized for mobile devices. Would it be a good idea to register a .mobi domain or is it better to use a subdomain (for example:http://m.////.TLD) for this site?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**If you can, the best option is to use responsive design,** and make your site work well in all modern mobile devices on the same domain and URL.

However, there are some situations where a different site is a better option. For example, when most of your audience has old mobile equipment, you think your users will prefer a different experience, or there is heavy use of flash in the desktop site.

An `m.example.com` subdomain is more usual today, and users will be more confident as they can be assured that the mobile site is not a phishing site, created by spammers using the same brand name/colors/logo.

In terms of SEO, if there's any difference (I think there isn't, but you never know whether search engine algorithms will change tomorrow), it will favor sub-domains.